# Speakers silent, headphones work in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: audio, ubuntu-9.04, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04.  Worked fine for months, then I rebooted yesterday after weeks of continuous operation.  Now audio won't play through the speakers.  The USB headset works fine, but the Conexant audio (CX20549) does not.  Weirdly, it *thinks* it's playing.  pavumeter shows appropriate levels, volume looks OK in alsamixer, but no sound.

I did find this page: http://www.eugeneteplitsky.com/fixing-silent-pulseaudio-in-ubuntu-9-04/

Unfortunately the advice there doesn't help me.  For one thing, the syntax for the alsa-base.conf file is apparently not actually documented anywhere.  For another, my chipset isn't listed in the kernel.org docs he links to!

EDIT: would upgrading to 9.10 help?  Is there a major change in the audio subsystem between 9.04 and 9.10?
Any suggestions?

EDIT 2: This is stranger than I thought.  Sound works normally in Xine, but is silent in Audacity, VLC and mplayer.  What the?

Comment: the link you're talking about is using modprobe-style options (like the ones found in `/etc/modprobe.d/*` ..).  you may also look into tweaks in a `.asoundrc`: http://alsa.opensrc.org/index.php/.asoundrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio using PulseAudio is very buggy by default in 9.04. It is improved in 9.10, but there are still issues.

You can try to solve it following this recommendations: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843012.

Also, it is worth considering Kubuntu, which doesn't use PulseAudio by default (this is true for the latest versions of Kubuntu).

Comment: I ended up upgrading to 9.10 (which I would have done soon anyway) and sound is working now. I will keep your suggestions and Quack's in mind should the problem return.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mixer settings.

For some reason it sometimes it goes to zero after a reboot (on some Ubuntu installations).

Comment: First thing I tried.  Those settings are fine.